# Fastening of 2nd layer of subfloor

Tags: flooring

I am installing hardwood flooring, and that hardwood will be run parallel to the joists because the joists run the long length of the room. Therefore I am adding a 2nd layer of subfloor, per the hardwood manufacturer directions. The manufacturer states to not fasten the 2nd layer to the joists.

My questions are when adding a second layer of subfloor what is the most appropriate fastener? Should that fastener completely penetrate the first layer, even if it's not to be fastened directly to the joists, and by how much quarter, half inch? Lastly, would the addition of an adhesive such as Great Stuff construction adhesive be of any benefit?